# WPF button padding not respected when applying a style

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having issues finding out why my padding is not being respected on the button when applying a style (with no padding attribtues).

#### Resource Dictionary

```
<Style x:Key="NoHoverDisabledButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ccc"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

#### Button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NoHoverDisabledButton}" Padding="20,0" x:Name="OnlineUpdateButton" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="0" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        ...
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

#### Result with style applied

[image]

#### Result when simply removing style from button

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: There is no element in your Button Template that actually uses the Padding property. Try `Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"` on the ContentPresenter.

Comment: @Clemens Do you mean in the `button` itself? I get `The member "padding" is not recognized or accessible` when doing that.

Comment: As said, the ContentPresenter

Comment: Ah, I couldn't initially find `ContentPresenter` but I see it now. That worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Padding` property of a control is typically meant to represent an "inner margin", i.e. be assigned to the `Margin` property of an element in the ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Border ...>
        <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" .../>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```